# Why does Ansible evaluate this variable, even inside a false if block?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

When Ansible encounters an `if` block, and the `if` condition involves the `groups` variable, it seems to expand the contents of the block *before* it has evaluated the `if` condition. This is causing an undefined variable error that the `if` condition would otherwise protect against.

Why does error occur? Is it expected behaviour, or a bug?

I've reduced the behaviour to a minimal test case.

inventory.yml

```
group1:

group2:
  hosts:
    localhost:
  vars:
    foo: "{{ groups.group1[0] }}"
```

#### Expected

An empty string, because in both cases the `if` condition is false

```
$ ansible -i inventory.yml group2 -mdebug -amsg="{% if false %}{{ foo }}{% endif %}"
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": ""
}
$ ansible -i inventory.yml group2 -mdebug -amsg="{% if groups.group1 %}{{ foo }}{% endif %}"
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

#### Actual

When the `if` condition involves the `groups` variable, `foo` is evaluated, resulting in an undefined variable message

```
$ ansible -i inventory.yml group2 -mdebug -amsg="{% if false %}{{ foo }}{% endif %}"
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": ""
}
$ ansible -i inventory.yml group2 -mdebug -amsg="{% if groups.group1 %}{{ foo }}{% endif %}"
localhost | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: list object has no element 0"
}
```

I'm using Ansible 2.7.9.

Answer (score 1):

Ansible expands templated keys on demand from the magical context dictionary it passes to Jinja, as Jinja requests them, however Jinja early-binds any name referenced by a template before any processing begins.

Jinja expects the context to yield either a concrete value or the equivalent of `KeyError` ("Undefined" IIRC), Ansible OTOH uses this moment to recursively invoke Jinja in order to build the value to pass to the original template invocation. It is in this recursive invocation that your error is occurring.

It may be helpful to look at the raw Jinja source for a similar template (prepared with `jinja2.Environment().compile(..., raw=True)`:

```python
from __future__ import division
from jinja2.runtime import LoopContext, TemplateReference, Macro, Markup, TemplateRuntimeError, missing, concat, escape, markup_join, unicode_join, to_string, identity, TemplateNotFound, Namespace
name = None

def root(context, missing=missing, environment=environment):
    resolve = context.resolve_or_missing
    undefined = environment.undefined
    if 0: yield None
    l_0_foo = resolve('foo')
    l_0_groups = resolve('groups')
    pass
    if environment.getattr((undefined(name='groups') if l_0_groups is missing else l_0_groups), 'group1'):
        pass
        yield to_string((undefined(name='foo') if l_0_foo is missing else l_0_foo))

blocks = {}
debug_info = '1=12'
```

Notice how the calls to `resolve()` complete before any conditional evaluation occurs. It is within `resolve()` that Ansible attempts to recursively expand your `foo` variable.

It should be possible to tweak things so that `foo` is only expanded should Jinja attempt to convert it to a string (or similar), so I'd suggest filing an upstream bug.

Comment: An alternative bug report / PR might be for Jinja -- it could be quite a straightforward optimization pass for its bytecode to promote the resolve() call as late as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ansilbe combined with Jinja2 will first evaluate the templated var as a string before effectively playing the condition hence your fail.

The ansible/jinja2 way to manage your case is to use the [`default`](https://ansible-docs.readthedocs.io/zh/stable-2.0/rst/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables) filter when defining `foo`

```
foo: "{{ groups.group1[0] | default('') }}"
```

And you then don't need to test for any other indirect value. Simply use the var

```
ansible -i inventory.yml group2 -mdebug -amsg="{{ foo }}"
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": ""
}
```

Answer (score -4):

It seems that `groups.group1[0]` is what is not defined.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm aware `groups.group1[0]` isn't defined. My intuition is that it would not be evaluated - because the surrounding if block evaluates to `false`. However it does. I'm asking: is my intuition wrong, or is Ansible?

Comment: Technically, it is the Jinja2 plugin, not Ansible.